# Filtrar los mensajes de VisibleDeprecationWarning

Tags: python, warnings

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente código:

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=7000, seed=6)
```

Me aparece el siguiente `warning`:

> :6: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/datasets/imdb.py:159: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
> x_train, y_train = np.array(xs[:idx]), np.array(labels[:idx])

Cómo no se arreglarlo he decidido al menos no mostrarlo. El problema es que estoy siendo incapaz de solo excluir este tipo `VisibleDeprecationWarning`. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

He intentado lo siguiente, pero no funciona,

```
# Este da error, lo cual es obvio pues esta categoría no aparece en la documentación

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=VisibleDeprecationWarning)
```

```
# Este no filtra mi warning

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```

Por ahora no filtro las categorías y funciona, pero me parece excesivo ya que podría tapar otros posibles *warnings*.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VisibleDeprecationWarning` no es un *warning* de python, sino del módulo numpy.

Prueba con esto:

```py
import warnings
import numpy as np

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=np.VisibleDeprecationWarning)
```